# Why styled-components overrides styles differently for its children?

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I have parent component with styling

```
> * {
    width: initial;
  }
```

And I have two different components:

```
<Component1/>
```

and

```
<Component2/>
```

they are both `div` with width of 200px, just have different elements inside. `Component2` was written today and I noticed that styling from parent is being overriden by its default styling. I can't understand why it's happening because both of those components were styled similarly.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I noticed that if I have styling in parent:

```
> * {
    width: initial;
  }
```

it will override styling of only my first component.

However, if I will change it to:

```
> div {
    width: initial;
  }
```

it will work properly. I guess `styled-components` thinks of `div` being more specific than `*`, to be honest I would expect it to be otherwise.

This is a solution that worked for me: to use exact container type like `div`, `section` etc. rather than `*`.